# Como obtengo el xpath correcto selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Me encuentro haciendo WebScrapping a la pagina del supermercado dia (https://www.dia.es/compra-online/).
Mi problema llega al conseguir el xpath para obtener el catalogo de productos, ya que si copio su xpath y corro el codigo salta un error diciendo que el string contiene espacios sin resolver ("The string '/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/header/cas:gateway/div[3]/div/a/span[2]' contains unresolvable namespaces.")
Os dejo mi código en bruto:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

driver_path = "chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(driver_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.dia.es/compra-online/')

time.sleep(2)

WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[10]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[2]'))) \
.click()

time.sleep(1)

WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/header/cas:gateway/div[3]/div/a/span[2]'))) \
.click()
```

Me seria de mucha ayuda si alguien sabe algo al respecto.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes optar por buscar por el nombre de la clase:  `CLASS_NAME`.

Dentro del sitio:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-product-catalog">
```

Para acceder al elemento y clickearlo:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-product-catalog'))) \
.click()
```

pd: imagino que estás teniendo en cuenta el botón de aceptar cookies que sale al ingresar a la página

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))) \
    .click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Sí necesitas obtener los submenus que se muestran a la izquierda, puedes hacer algo como esto:

Buscar el elemento del submenu, el nombre de la clase contiene un espacio, entonces la mejor manera de acceder es agregarle un punto "." al inicio del selector, y donde veas un espacio, agregarle otro punto ".".

• En el sitio aparece `class="nav-submenu ff-montse"`

• Para acceder  `'.nav-submenu.ff-montse'`

Y finalmente mostrar el nombre de cada categoría y mostrar el link asociado a cada una.

```
submenu = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.nav-submenu.ff-montse')))
for i in submenu.find_elements_by_tag_name('li'):
    if i.text != "":
        print(i.text)
        print(i.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href'))
```

salida:

```
Novedades
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/novedades-DIA-online
Dulces de Navidad
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/dulces-de-navidad/cf
Platos Preparados
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/platos-preparados/cf
Frescos
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/frescos/cf
Despensa
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/despensa/cf
Bebidas
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/bebidas/cf
Bodega
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/bodega/cf
Congelados
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/congelados/cf
Cuidado Personal
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/cuidado-personal/cf
Bebé
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/bebe/cf
Cuidado del Hogar
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/cuidado-del-hogar/cf
Mascotas
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/mascotas/cf
Ofertas
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/ofertas-DIA-online
El truco del día
https://www.dia.es/compra-online/el-truco-del-dia
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tanto por la solución, como por la aportación.